# json data char '&' disturbs ajax post request data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

i am generating a json string using `JSON.stringify` and my json string will be like

```
jsonstring=[{"step1":[{"nm":"John & joe"},{"title":"Hello & hai"}]},{"step2":[{"desc":"1234"},{"usr":"abc@xyz.com"}]}]`
```

i am escaping `&` with `\&` and sending this json string to server through ajax.

```
$.ajax({
url:"test-usr-data.php",
type:"post",
data:"usrdata="+jsonstring,
success: function(response){
console.log("data is "+response); 
},
complete:function (jqXHR, textStatus){ 
console.log("ajax Request completed"+textStatus);
    }
});
```

The problem is with `&` char in json string, even though i am escaping `&` to `\&` data is not posted to server but ajax request status is success.

I tried removing `&` from json string it works fine and data is posting to server correctly.

Can any one help me in correct way to escaping `&` in json string.

Comment: Why are people upvoting that comment?  It's wrong.

Comment: ya i tried &amp; but it is not working

Comment: It's the comment suggesting `&amp;` that's wrong.  The right way to encode a `&` in POST data is `%26`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Who told you that escaping in URL's works by prepending a backslash?

jQuery will take care of it, just do

```
data: {usrdata: jsonstring},
```

FYI: You could use `encodeURIComponent` as well

```
data: "usrdata=" + encodeURIComponent(jsonstring),
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to URI encode a `&` is as `%26`, given that 0x26 (38) is the ASCII code for that character.

But don't, use the `data: { key: value, ... }` way of passing parameters to `$.ajax` instead, and have jQuery do it all for you.